# Swift : How do I pass the same text and image form tableVC to a detailVC using the same tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, uitableview

I'm trying to pass the same (text + image ) from tableVC  to the detail tableVC using an array populated in tableVC.

It is working in tableVC but no data passed into the detailVC.

They share one tableviewcell.

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
}
```

tableVC

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var thecourseName = [String]()
var theimg = [UIImage]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  thecourseName = ["course 1 ","course 2 ","course 3 "]
 theimg = [UIImage(named: "109.png")!,UIImage(named: "110.png")!]
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.title.text = thecourseName[indexPath.row]
    cell.date.text = date[indexPath.row]
    cell.img.image = UIImage[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if ( segue == "toInfo") {
        var text = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var detailsVC: DetalisTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalisTableViewController
    detailsVC.courseName = thecourseName

    }

}
```

One error in `cell.img.image = UIImage[indexPath.row]

detailVC

```
import UIKit
```

class DetalisTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
   var courseName = [String]()

@IBOutlet var passedCourse: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return courseName.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.title.text = courseName[indexPath.row]




    return cell
}
```

StoryBoard 
http://s18.postimg.org/mwkw5hf1l/image.png

Answer (score 1):

To fix your first error change `cell.img.image = UIImage[indexPath.row]` to `cell.img.image = theimg[indexPath.row]`

Comment: fixed the first one thank you bro , if you can help me to pass the image and the title to the detailVC

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if ( segue == "toInfo") {
        var text = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var detailsVC: DetalisTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalisTableViewController
        detailsVC.courseName = thecourseName

    }
}
```

`var text = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` is not text it is an indexPath

and in the scope of this function there is no way that `thecourseName` is what you expect that it should be. I think what you want is something more along these lines.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if ( segue == "toInfo") {
        var text = thecourseName[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()]
        var detailsVC: DetalisTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalisTableViewController
        detailsVC.courseName = text

    }
}
```

That should give you the text for the selected cell and set it for the `variable` of the details View.